# Why is second level generics not possible in Java

Tags: java, generics

**Long story short:**
Why is the following not possible in Java?

```
public class Test<A<B>> {} // A and B both being generic parameters.
```

> *Note: I don't have any specific use case right now, rather I am just trying to understand why this is not allowed.*

At first I thought because the compiler **cannot** assert if `A` can accept generics parameter because after compiling `A`, due to type erasure the generics won't be present anymore.

But, if that is the case, then we cannot use generics on any class at all. So I took out the byte code of a generic class and found that there is metadata to say it accepts generics.

```
public class com.Test<T> {
  public com.Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

And I did a quick search and [SO confirmed compiled code will have generics related metadata too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

**So why does the compiler not allow multilevel generics?**

Will there be any problem in allowing it? Is it a limitation? or something else?

Comment: A wild guess: it would make the rules of the type system too complex even for its authors to fully grasp. And it would probably have very low usefulness---as you noted yourself by failing to come up with any use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that this class **was** actually compiling:

```
public class Test<A<B>> { .. }
```

This implies that *a proper* instantiation of the class would be:

```
new Test<Class<Integer>>()
//or
new Test<List<String>>()
```

and the following wouldn't be correct (since the provided type-parameter is not generic):

```
new Test<String>();
//or
new Test<Object>();
```

However, a type-parameter *should not* be restricted for being generic or not - it should just hold some meta information about the *type* (and as it turns out, this is the *type* after type-erasure has taken place) with which it would be replaced.

Type-erasure itself can be another possible reason for not allowing such constructions. Let's again consider the above `Test` class was correctly defined and you had this:

```
new Test<Class<Integer>>();
```

When type-erasure happens, `<A<B>>` should be replaced with `Class<Integer>`, however, due to the erasure, we'd have only a `Class` (even though internally it would contain info about the `Integer` type) - expecting a `Class<Integer>`, but providing a `Class` should not be correct.

Thanks for the interesting question!

Answer (score 3):

Scala calls it higher kinded types. So it's definitely a feasible abstraction. Adding it to Java has — to my knowledge — never been seriously considered.

Sadly, I can't find any good introductory text to Scala's higher kinded types. The best I can find is the original paper [Generics of a Higher Kind](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/186940/4/tcpoly.pdf); here's its abstract:

> With Java 5 and C# 2.0, first-order parametric polymorphism was introduced in mainstream object-oriented programming languages under the name of *generics*. Although the first-order variant of generics is very useful, it also imposes some restrictions: it is possible to abstract over a type, but the resulting type constructor cannot be abstracted over. This can lead to code duplication. We removed this restriction in Scala, by allowing type constructors as type parameters and abstract type members. This paper presents the design and implementation of the resulting type constructor polymorphism. Furthermore, we study how this feature interacts with existing object-oriented constructs, and show how it makes the language more expressive.